# How do I dynamically call a class and use it's functions?

Tags: c#, class, function, reflection, call

I have a problem trying to dynamically call my class. This is my example code:

Class:

```
namespace TestUseCase
{
    public class UseCase11
    {
        public UseCase11()
        {
        }

        public string init()
        {
            return "aa.aspx";
        }
    }
}
```

Method to call the class:

```
private void dynamicExecution(string ClassName, string FunctionName)
{
    System.Reflection.Assembly assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();
    Object[] para = new Object[1];
    para[0] = null;
    object dynMyClass = assembly.CreateInstance(ClassName);
    dynMyClass.GetType().GetMethod(FunctionName).Invoke(dynMyClass, para);
}
```

Usage:

```
    dynamicExecution("TestUseCase.UseCase11", "init");
```

Unfortunately the result is always `null`. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: try, in your dynamicExecution method :  `assembly.GetTypes().Where(m => m.Name == "UseCase11").Select(x => x.FullName).FirstOrDefault();` to see if you're in the right assembly and write the correct type full name.

Comment: plz help me about your code, where i add this code in my method, and whate is the WHERE in your code?!!

Comment: put it in your dynamicExecution method (with a `var test = <mycode>;`). I you don't get any result in test, that's an assembly problem. If you have a result, see the value of test.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the class you are attempting to instantiate is declared in the right assembly. In your example you are using `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()` but is that the correct assembly? If the class is defined in the same assembly as the code that you have shown you could also use `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()`.

Comment: I want my classes to dynamically call and my classes not dll or other file, but i search about this subject, everyone use this way to call class and functions!!! i change code to your answer but so "dynMyClass" is null :(

Comment: In which assembly is the `UseCase11` class defined? You need to load this assembly. I don't understand what you mean by `I want my classes to dynamically call and my classes not dll or other file`.

Comment: i have several class in app_code folder, i want get 2 parameter (class name , method name) and use class and method (call dynamically)

Comment: @mohammadabedi Do you "several *assemblies*" by chance?